# asp.net iText dll implementation help

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, itext

I have a function for reading and creating a pdf file. I was told it uses iText.dll, but not sure where to find it and implement it. Can anyone point me in the right direction. Im a .net newbie. I dont need help with the code right now, so just setting up the dependancies would be a good start.

Any help would be great

Thanks

--Mark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean the component iTextSharp

You can find THE download and documentation here:

http://itextsharp.sourceforge.net/